# Magento Sales Order View returns 404

Tags: php, magento

Whenever I want to navigate from the Magento Admin dashboard to the **order** section I get redirected to a 404, strangely this is not a 404 from the Magento dashboard, but one from my website itself.

The URL to the orders from the dashboard is `[sitename]/index.php/admin/sales_order/index/key/[key-value]/`

However, whenever I navigate to `[sitename]/index.php/admin/sales_order`, I can access and see my latest orders. (navigating to this URL manually every time isn't very convenient of course..)

Has anybody else ever experienced this before? 
Any solution, answer or insight would be great :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are seeing the default server 404, your request is never reaching php at all. This means that your problem is probably in an .htaccess routing rule, not in php. Try manually removing 'index.php' from the uri and see if that works. If so, it will give you a clue how to fix the routing rule. Also check your apache log for clues. Default error pages appear when apache does not know how to connect your request with a file, and the default server page is shown instead as a catchall.

Comment: @mopsyd I tried removing index.php from the URI but it returns me the same error page. The 'invoices' page, alsof from Sales, does show and has the same kind of URL, so I don't think my .htaccess is the problem.. (I double checked the whole .htaccess file, of course), also the log file isn't telling me anything.. Thanks for your input though :).

Answer (score 2):

This could be the result of a previous Magento security patch. Do you have any extensions or custom code around the Sales Order page in your admin?

In the past, an admin module could adopt the `[sitename]/index.php/admin` structure, or it could define its own... something like `[sitename]/adminmod/`.

However, it was discovered that these custom admin url structures were vulnerable and, as of SUPEE 6788, they no longer function. All admin modules must follow the `[sitename]/index.php/admin` structure.

> ...strangely this is not a 404 from the Magento dashboard, but one from
>   my website itself.

This is what makes me think this could be the issue. Now that those custom paths are no longer recognized as admin pages, they get re-routed to the front-end, which is why you would see your typical customer-facing 404.

If this is the case, a fix could be as simple as updating the affected modules. By now, most vendors should have updated files that repair this issue.

For more information on the patch itself:

https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details

**Edit:**
Sometime yesterday, Magento released a patch that doesn't address security issues, but instead issues caused by previous patches. One of those issues would have prevented you from seeing sales information, if you are using PHP 5.3. Under **PHP 5.3 Compatibility (SUPEE-7882)**:

> The patch was not compatible with PHP 5.3 for earlier versions of Magento that were still supporting this version. Merchants experiencing this issue were unable to view sales information in the Admin.

https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-7405